# Number of states in a LFSR

Tags: stream-cipher, lfsr

Do all $2^{\ell}$ (where $\ell$ is the bit length of the shift register) states always occur in a LFSR or can I choose my taps badly so some states are skipped and the period is shortened?

If so is there a way to prove the number of states that can occur in a LFSR?

Comment: Found some info that you might find interesting: http://www.cryogenius.com/software/lfsr/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As fgrieu points out, the number of states reached is at most $2^\ell-1$ and that is achieved only if the feedback polynomial is a primitive polynomial (and the initial state is not all 
zero). If the feedback polynomial is *irreducible* but **not** primitive, then with
nonzero initial loading, the LFSR state will cycle through $N$ states, where $N$ is a
*divisor* of $2^\ell-1$ but *not* a divisor of $2^m-1$ for any $m$ that is itself a proper divisor
of $\ell$. For example, if the feedback polynomial is an irreducible but nonprimitive polynomial of degree $6$, then, depending on which polynomial is being considered, the 
LFSR will cycle through $21$ states, or through $9$ states. The $63$ nonzero states
form $3$ cycles of $21$ states each, or $7$ cycles of $9$ states each. Depending on
the initial loading, the LFSR will cycle through one of these cycles (and the other
cycles will never occur).

For an *arbitrary* feedback polynomial, which could be reducible, that is,
factorable into a product of (not necessarily distinct) irreducible polynomials
(meaning something like $[f(x)]^2g(x)$ might be the factorization),
the answer is *much* messier and complicated to describe. Search for the
term *period of a polynomial* and read Lidl and Neiderriter's *Finite
Fields* or Chapter 6 of Berlekamp's *Algebraic Coding Theory* for some
of the details.

Answer (score 5):

Read [chapter 6](http://cacr.uwaterloo.ca/hac/about/chap6.pdf) of the [HAC](http://cacr.uwaterloo.ca/hac/).

It will tell you that no, the $2^ℓ$ states are never reached, at most $2^ℓ-1$ are. And that occurs for taps chosen per a primitive polynomial, and initial state not all zero.

For lists of primitive polynomials, I use [jj's useful and ugly page of mathematical data](http://www.jjj.de/mathdata/).